# <?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>, link image, yii2

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, yii2

In yii 1 I linked images using following code:

```
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>../../images/header_pic.jpg">
```

But, when I used this code in yii 2, it showed error. I do not know how to use it in yii2.

Answer (score 0):

`theme` is a property of the view application component, you should use :

```
Yii::$app->view->theme->baseUrl
```

Read more about [Theming in Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-theming.html).

Comment: i found answer: <?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>